# How to correctly bind a property from model to property in hand-made Item in delegate?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols2

I want to make an editing delegate for a `ListView` for an arbitrary model.
In delegate I want to use my own `NeatInput` inherited from `TextInput`. `NeatInput` declares own property `realValue`, binds `text` to `realValue`, and, to make it two-way, upon `textChanged` signal changes realValue. That works as expected:

```js
/*NeatInput.qml*/

import QtQuick 2.0
TextInput {
    width: 50
    property real realValue: 0.0
    text: realValue * 2
    onTextChanged: {
        realValue = Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) / 2
    }
}
```

Now, it is used simply as a delegate in `ListView`, with binding `realValue` on `someValue` from model, and, for edit purpose, writing to `someValue` upon `realValueChanged`:

```js
/*main.qml*/
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
  
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true
    
    ListView {
        id: view
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                someValue: 50
            }
        }
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: Row {
            NeatInput {
                realValue: someValue
                onRealValueChanged: someValue = realValue
            }

            SpinBox {
                value: someValue
                onValueChanged: someValue = value
            }
            Text {
                width: 50
                text: someValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Text` for simple reading, `SpinBox` for read/write with standard Item.

But this doesn't work as I expect:

- Editing from `SpinBox` updates `Text` *only*;
- Editing from `NeatInput` updates *both* `SpinBox` and `Text`.

So, binding on `someValue` for `NeatInput` is broken someway, but writes work.
If I remove signal binding `onTextChanged` from `NeatInput.qml`, then:

- Editing from `SpinBox` updates *both* `Text` and `NeatInput`;
- Editing from `NeatInput` updates *nothing*.

What should I do to make updates work from both editors to all readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is always: **assignments break bindings**. Whenever you do this:

```
    onTextChanged: {
        realValue = Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) / 2
    }
```

it breaks the binding that you created here:

```
    realValue: someValue
```

So the first time `text` changes, `realValue` will stop listening for updates to `someValue`.

Two-way bindings are always tricky because they become circular. I played with your code for a minute and got it working by doing this:

```
    ListView {
        id: view
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                someValue: 50
            }
        }
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: Row {
            NeatInput {
                realValue: someValue
                onRealValueChanged: someValue = realValue

                property real someValueCopy: someValue
                onSomeValueCopyChanged:
                {
                    realValue = someValueCopy;
                }
            }

            SpinBox {
                value: someValue
                onValueChanged: someValue = value
            }
            Text {
                width: 50
                text: someValue
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And for standard SpinBox it is not the case, because it is C++ inside, and there is two-way binding written manually, right?